# Pandas concat keeps adding new index columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm pretty new to Python and Pandas, and having a concat(?)-problem with my small project. The code works almost as it's meant to work, but when running it multiple times in a row, it keeps adding new index-columns. This is something I don't want it to do. I've been trying all sort of tricks like dropping first column, hiding index and resetting index, but couldn't get it work. I could delete extra columns in Excel but I think it can be solved by changing the code somehow.

About Excel-data: First row includes column titles and there are no indices.

Do you people know what's wrong with my code?
You can also suggest improvements :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


table1_data = r'C:\Users\--->file1.xlsx'
table2_data = r'C:\Users\--->file2.xlsx' # this is always new data 
database_data = r'C:\Users\--->file3xlsx'

table1 = pd.read_excel(table1_data, header=0, index_col=None,keep_default_na=True)
table2 = pd.read_excel(table2_data, header=0, index_col=None,keep_default_na=True)
database = pd.read_excel(database_data, header=0, index_col=None,keep_default_na=True)


sold = table1[~table1.License.isin(table2.License)]
sold['Deleted'] = table2.loc[1,'Deleted']

database = pd.concat([database, sold])

s = sold.set_index('License')['Deleted']
table1['Deleted'] = table1['License'].map(s).fillna(table1['Deleted']).astype('datetime64[ns]')

cond = table1['License'].isin(sold['License'])
table1.drop(table1[cond].index, inplace = True)

bought = table2[~table2.License.isin(table1.License)]
bought['Deleted'] = ''

table1 = pd.concat([table1,bought])




database.to_excel(r'C:\Users\--->file3.xlsx')
table1.to_excel(r'C:\Users\--->file1.xlsx')
```

[Something like this happens when running code multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RumRd.png)

Comment: Welcome Viimu, please provide sample data in a code block. You can get the samples with `df.head(10).to_dict('split')`

Comment: Okey, so... it is something like this:

{'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 'columns': ['Unnamed: 0',
  'Unnamed: 0.1',
  'Brand_model',
  'Model_brand_url',
  'License',
  'Price',
  'Year',
  'Kilometers',
  'Transmission',
  'Fuel',
  'Added',
  'Deleted'],
 'data': [[0.0,
   0.0,
   'Audi RS5',
   'https-link',
   'Licence plate number',
   108900,
   2018,
   40710,
   ' Automatic',
   ' Gasolin',
   Timestamp('2020-09-04 00:00:00'),
   nan],

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ignore_index=True`:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(data={"c1": [1, 2], "c2": [3, 4]})
B = pd.DataFrame(data={"c3": [5, 6], "c4": [7, 8]})

C = pandas.concat([A, B], ignore_index=True)
```

```
C
--------------------
|   |c1 |c2 |c3 | c4|
------------------
| 0 |1  |3  |NaN|NaN|
| 1 |2  |4  |NaN|NaN|
| 2 |NaN|NaN|5  |7  |
| 3 |NaN|NaN|6  |8  |
---------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, but it (ignore_index=True) didn't work. It keeps adding columns when I'm running the code multiple times.